# Blocking Queue usage scenario

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, blocking, blockingqueue

I am working on a design where I am processing all the exceptions caught in catch blocks to send to a server via webservice call.

The idea is not to block the main app at all while doing this job. I felt blocking queue pattern is appropriate for it. So, I created a blocking queue using array implementation with size 10. At the start of the main app I am initializing a consumer thread for this queue.

However, the producer side is little confusing to me. as per my understanding if, queue is full and if the main app hit an exception then doing a producer.put(object) would be blocked until queue has space and hence the main app will block too. is that correct understanding?

Comment: Yes, Producer thread will be blocked until Consumer thread take one from the queue.

Comment: hmm then it is not good as the catch block will hung and that means main app will be hung too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. Here is a very useful [table of BlockingQueue methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) 
Usually it is good to have a bounded queue, but the limit should not be very low.

Comment: it's for a mobile app so dont want to let it cause out of memory issues. hence kept it ver conservative 10. But it will block then should I do the queue operation by creating anonymous threads ?

Comment: 100 or even 1000 would be a lot too, because in case of mobile app there could be no network connection, and in this case you couldn't send exceptions to a server. I suggest you to use `offer(e)`, because otherwise in case of network errors or restarting server your producing threads could be blocked. Also you can have some counter for cases when `offer(e)` returns `false` and from time to time flush it to server if it's greater then 0

Comment: well for the consumer side the idea to make a call and if it fails due to network issues then push it to local sqllite db.  so that they could be retried later from DB.

Comment: Good choiсе, then it could look like this 'if (!queue.offer(e)) { //write into sqllite }

Comment: one of the chellange is see with this is assume someone in the main app making some 20 calls to server and all 20 fails due to server down etc. then i end up having 20 queue operations and say queue is full. then all 20 will end up in to sql db. this local sql db is a single threaded instance. hence it wlll still cause lag to the main app.

Comment: I'm not expert in mobile development. But in server-side development it usually takes nanoseconds to make dozens of insertions into a db (especially in a batch mode) so it can't become noticeable. Also such operations as sending/storing logs shouldn't be done in main thread, but in a background instead.

Comment: well, yes this all be a background thread. on the question of it should be done in a main app. I agree if you have a single main app. We have many apps so we want a isolated solution which any of the app can uptake rather hard wiring.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should write your exception to phone storage(SharedPreferences if Android) instead of keeping in main memory.
First, it will not block your main app.

And on network connected call back, start a thread which will read from shared preferences and send it to the server.

Comment: well a local sqlLite DB is indeed a required component to handle situation when device is not connected to the network. however, writing to it is costly and it is a single thread db so in situations where too many exceptions are generated the overall system will be overwhelmed.

Comment: Synchornize your DAO methods and use AsyncTasks to write exceptions to DB. Which means only on AsyncTask will be allowed to write exception to DB, while main app will not be hanged because we are using AsyncTasks.